# Can a halting configurations of a Turing Machine has the same state of another configuration has?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

At first, I believed since the state a halting configuration is at will be a halting state, whenever a configuration goes into that state, the TM halts.
Hence, there should not exist two configurations that appear at a different time that have the same current state.

However, after reading some introductions of the One-state Turing machine, I start getting confused about my initial conclusion since to my understanding, a one-state Turing machine will have its start state as accept state.
Can anyone explain this to me?

We use the 3rd edition of Sipser's *Introduction of Computation* as our textbook and here is the definition of a Turing machine from the book:

> DEFINITION 3.3 A Turing machine is a 7-tuple, $(Q,Σ,Γ,δ,q_0,q_{\mathit{accept}},q_{\mathit{reject}})$, where $Q, Σ, Γ$ are all ﬁnite sets and
>
> 1. $Q$ is the set of states,
> 2. $Σ$ is the input alphabet not containing the blank symbol $␣$,
> 3. $Γ$ is the tape alphabet, where $␣ ∈Γ$ and $Σ⊆Γ$,
> 4. $δ\colon Q×Γ\to Q×Γ×\{L,R\}$ is the transition function,
> 5. $q_0 ∈Q$ is the start state,
> 6. $q_{\mathit{accept}} ∈Q$ is the accept state, and
> 7. $q_{\mathit{reject}} ∈Q$ is the reject state, where $q_{\mathit{reject}} \neq q_{\mathit{accept}}$.

Comment: There are a gazillion different definitions of Turing machines. You will have to provide the definition you're referring to.

Comment: I just updated with more information. Thank you!

Comment: The syntax of the Turing machine is not enough. We also need to know its semantics – how it operates. Also, please try to use LaTeX.

Comment: Your definition is about multi-state Turing machines. Since it requires the accepting state and the rejecting state to be different, there are always at least two different states. Do you have a particular definition of one-state Turing machines in mind? The latter might have a different stopping convention than usual Turing machines.

Comment: So if we break the question into separate pieces first to reduce confusion and we don't consider one-state TM: by the definition of Sipser's textbook, is it possible to have two configurations appears at a different time to have the same current state while one (or both of them) being a halting configuration?

Comment: This depends on the semantics of the model, which you haven't indicated. But presumably, a Turing machine halts upon reaching a halting state, and in particular, such a configuration cannot appear twice.

Comment: Is the semantics referring to the transition rule?

Comment: It refers to the definition of the language that the Turing machine accepts.